# Join based on maximum overlap in PostGIS/PostGresQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have two sets of polygons in two tables. The sets overlap each other. For each polygon in set A, I would like to get the ID of the polygon in set B that it overlaps the most. I'm using PostgreSQL with the PostGIS extension.

I know just enough about SQL to know that you can only join based on true/false conditions. So this won't work:

```
SELECT
  a.id as a_id,
  b.id as b_id,
FROM
  a
JOIN
  b
ON
  max(ST_Area(ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom)))
```

because max() can't be in the ON clause.

`ST_Intersects()` is a true/false test, so I **could** join on that, but polygons in set A will often overlap with more than one polygon in set B, and I need to know which one overlaps the **most**. ST_Intersects would presumably just return the first overlapping ID it came across, regardless of the extent of the overlap.

This seems like it should be do-able, but it's beyond me. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (a.id)
  a.id as a_id,
  b.id as b_id,
  ST_Area(ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom)) as intersect_area
FROM a, b
ORDER BY a.id, ST_Area(ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom)) DESC
```

It:

1) Calculates ST_Area(ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom)) for every (a,b) pair of records.

2) Orders them by a.id and by intersect_area when a.id are equal.

3) In every group of equal a.id it picks the firs record (the first record has the highest intersect_area because of ordering on step 2).

Comment: That solves the problem very neatly. Thank you thank you! `DISTINCT ON` is new to me -- very handy in this context.

Comment: When I try this polygons in A that does not overlap with anyone in B still gets an b.id and a 0 intersections area. This can be avoided with `WHERE st_intersects(a.geom,b.geom)`